# split method of String class not working as expected

Tags: java, android, string, file-io

I want to read string line by line from a file
Each line is two integers seperated by two tabs, and end of line is a `\n` character, as shown below in [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)

[image]

Here is my code to read from this file:

```
public void btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click(View view){
    String[] arr = new String[2];
    String rejoinAfterSplit = "";
    try {
        instream = new FileInputStream(mRcordFilePath);
        if (instream != null) {
              // prepare the file for reading
              InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
              BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
              String line;
              // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
              do {
                 line = buffreader.readLine();

                 // arr = line.split(" ");
                 arr = line.trim().split("\\s+");
                  rejoinAfterSplit += arr[0] +"\t\t" +  arr[1] + "\n";
                 // rejoinAfterSplit += line + "\n" ;
              } while (line != null);

              textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText(rejoinAfterSplit);
              // textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText("TEST");
        }

        instream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}       // btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click       CLOSED
```

When this function executes I get the following error:

```
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): Process: com.example.fourcommandmenu, PID: 14211
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    ... 11 more
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.example.fourcommandmenu.CompressionActivity.btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click(CompressionActivity.java:92)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    ... 14 more
```

The main error is

```
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    ... 11 more
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 17:19:51.981: E/AndroidRuntime(14211):    at com.example.fourcommandmenu.CompressionActivity.btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click(CompressionActivity.java:92)
```

The line in question is

```
arr = line.trim().split("\\s+");
```

I have tried variants of this line, such as `arr = line.split(" ");` and they don't work. I have verified that the program, upto `line = buffreader.readLine();`, works as expected.

How do I fix this? Please help. Thank you.

**--- EDIT1 ---**:

Here is the updated function:

```
public void btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click(View view){
    String[] arr = new String[2];
    String rejoinAfterSplit = "";
    try {
        instream = new FileInputStream(mRcordFilePath);
        if (instream != null) {
              // prepare the file for reading
              InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
              BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
              String line ="";
              // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time

              /*
              do {
                 line = buffreader.readLine();

                  arr = line.split(" ");
                 // arr = line.split("\\t\\t");
                 // arr = line.trim().split("\\t\\t");
                  rejoinAfterSplit += arr[0] +"\t\t" +  arr[1] + "\n";
                 // rejoinAfterSplit += line + "\n" ;
              } while (line != null);
              */

              while (line != null){
                     line = buffreader.readLine();

                      arr = line.split(" ");
                     // arr = line.split("\\t\\t");
                     // arr = line.trim().split("\\t\\t");
                      rejoinAfterSplit = rejoinAfterSplit + (arr[0] +"\t\t" +  arr[1] + "\n");
                     // rejoinAfterSplit += line + "\n" ;

              }

              textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText(rejoinAfterSplit);
              // textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText("TEST");
        }

        instream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}       // btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click       CLOSED

}       // CompressionActivity extends ActionBarActivity        CLOSED
```

Now I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error:

```
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324): Process: com.example.fourcommandmenu, PID: 15324
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    ... 11 more
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    at com.example.fourcommandmenu.CompressionActivity.btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click(CompressionActivity.java:107)
01-30 17:39:03.661: E/AndroidRuntime(15324):    ... 14 more
```

The array index error is at the line

```
 rejoinAfterSplit = rejoinAfterSplit + (arr[0] +"\t\t" +  arr[1] + "\n");
```

in the code after Edit1.

**--- EDIT2 ---**:

This is the code to test whether `line = buffreader.readLine();` is working correctly

```
public void btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click(View view){
    String[] arr = new String[2];
    String rejoinAfterSplit = "";
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        instream = new FileInputStream(mRcordFilePath);
        if (instream != null) {
              // prepare the file for reading
              InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
              BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
              String line ="";
              // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time

              // /*
              do {
                 line = buffreader.readLine();

                 // arr = line.split(" ");
                 // arr = line.split("\\t\\t");
                 // arr = line.trim().split("\\t\\t");
                 // rejoinAfterSplit += arr[0] +"\t\t" +  arr[1] + "\n";
                  rejoinAfterSplit += line + "\n" ;
              } while (line != null);
              // */

              textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText(rejoinAfterSplit);
              // textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText("TEST");
        }

        instream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}       // btnReadInSituValsCmprAct_click       CLOSED
```

From the value of `rejoinAfterSplit` I can see that `readline()` itself is working correctly. However, if I uncomment the next line `arr = line.split(" ");` the activity crashes with NullPointerException at this line.

Comment: show about `split("\\t\\t");`

Comment: I have verified that `line` has the expected value

Comment: `split("\\t\\t");` gives the same `NullPointerException`

Comment: @user13267 - You are having a NPE.. Checkline 92 --> `CompressionActivity.java:92`

Comment: The problem is occurring at last line. Its a do-while loop... do is executed before while. So... for last line, `line != null` is true but then, you read next line in the do-block again... which make `line` null... so you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: I know the NPE is at that line, but I couldn't find a cause for it

Comment: trying while(line != null){...} instead of do{..}while(line != null)

Comment: @user13267: before calling `split` what you are getting in `line` ?

Comment: `line` has the expected value, I will try @Sarvesh and @cyn0 's suggestions

Comment: Please see the update. it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error now.

Comment: it's still not going to work like that, because line can be set to null by readline even if it passes the while() test. add if(line == null) break; straight after the readline call

Comment: This file has 64 such lines, then the last line is a single `\n` character. Does that make any difference?

Comment: yes it does because you'll get a zero length array returned by split()

Comment: Please read [some tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) about reading files using `BufferedReader` correctly. And this method call `line.split(" ");` makes no sense. You said the numbers are delimited by two tab characters ... why do you split using a single white space?

Comment: please have a look at edit 2

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? When you get NPEs, run the program in a debugger and see which things are null. Same for ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions, run the debugger, see what is wrong - Stackoverflow is not a debugging place.

Comment: @user13267 a `do/while` loop is not appropriate for this context. You should use a `while` loop: `while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) { ... }`. This loop will exit if the read line is `null`. Therefore you won't get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code:

```
do {
    line = buffreader.readLine();

    String[] arr = line.trim().split("\t\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        rejoinAfterSplit += arr[i] + "\n";
    }
} while (line != null);
// */

textViewMiscDispCmprAct.setText(rejoinAfterSplit);
```

Comment: And how does this avoid the `NullPointerException`? A `while`is much better in this context.

Comment: did you added the above code to your application,is it working?

Comment: To *my* application? I'm not OP. And I don't need to test this code to see, that you're not handling a returned `null` value at the `line = buffreader.readLine();` line.